# How to create a array with "n" random integers?

Tags: java, arrays, random, arraylist, integer

Create two `Integer` `ArrayLists` containing n ​elements each where n​​ will be taken from the user.

so basically if a user inputs '6' two arrays with 6 elements needs to be created.
How would I do this?

This is what I have.. but its not even remotely correct.

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter a integer 'n' ");
    int x= input.nextInt();

    int[] a = { 1, 4, 9, 16 };
    int[] b = { 9, 7, 4, 9, 11 };
```

Comment: Well to start with, you're creating arrays. Those aren't the same as ArrayLists. So you should read up on ArrayLists. Next, you should read up on random numbers in Java. Next, you should read up on loops.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filling my arrays with random numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205651/filling-my-arrays-with-random-numbers)

Comment: I would add some clarification as to what those arrays need to have in them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take input from the user by using a scanner like this -

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the array size: ");
int n = input.nextInt();
```

Now create a function `generateRandomArray(int n)` like this -

```
public List<Integer> generateRandomArray(int n){
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    Random random = new Random();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        list.add(random.nextInt(1000));
    }
   return list;
}
```

Here - `random.nextInt(1000)` will generate a random number from the range 0 to 1000. You can fix the range as you want.

Now you can call the function with the value `n` get from the user -

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = generateRandomArray(n);
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = generateRandomArray(n);
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to generate random integer array from an interval, here are the options

```
// generate 100 random number between 0 to 100 
int[]  randomIntsArray = IntStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt(100)).limit(100).toArray();
//generate 100 random number between 100 to 200
int[]  randomIntsArray = IntStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextInt(100) + 100).limit(100).toArray();
```

Comment: To create a random integer array from an interval using streams, the better option would be to do e.g. [`int[] array = new Random().ints(100, 0, 100).toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)).  That avoids creating a new `Random` instance for each random number and, in my opinion, is clearer.

Comment: Just to be precise, your code generate 100 random number **between 0 to 99**
And between **100 and 199**.  
from [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) `Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)`

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness since [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) you can

1. Generate an int stream from the next int from a Random number
   Generator as a Supplier `()->r.nextInt()`
2. Limit the stream to your desired size
3. Convert it to Array

   `int[]  randomIntsArray=IntStream.generate(r::nextInt).limit(size).toArray()`

Comment: Also check out [`Random#ints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints()) and its overloads (all added in Java 8).

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter a integer 'n' ");
int x= input.nextInt();

int[] a = new int[x];
int[] b = new int[x];
```

This is basically integer array not array list

for array list you need to create it using

```
 List<Integer> integerList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ThreadLocalRandom**

```java
int[] a = IntStream.range(0, n).map(i -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x = input.nextInt();

    int[] a = new int[x];
    int[] b = new int[x];
```

Then you can populate values however you need them

Comment: @lacraig2 He was unclear as to what he wanted, in his code he has arrays and says he needs arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First create your ArrayList of Integers. Then you can add however many Integers as you'd like.

```
ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ar.add(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't duplicate what others have said, since it is sufficient, but perhaps understanding the difference between ArrayLists and Arrays will benefit you.

[ArrayList Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

[Array Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

ArrayLists grow dynamically, while Arrays have a fixed size. You can find how to populate them by following the excellent answers provided by the others.

Answer (score 0):

**Since 1.8**

```
// Since, as per your question, you're using arrays even though
// you state you want ArrayLists, we will assume you know why you're
// doing so.
int[] a = new int[x];
int[] b = new int[x];
Random random = new Random();
IntUnaryOperator unaryOpInt = (p) -> random.nextInt(maxIntVal);
// populate array a with random numbers
Arrays.setAll(a, unaryOpInt); 
// populate array b with random numbers
Arrays.setAll(b, unaryOpInt); 
// Since, as per your question, you require ArrayLists, you can
// create ArrayLists from arrays a and b as follows.
// create an ArrayList from array a
ArrayList<Integer> aArrList = new ArrayList<>(IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
// create an ArrayList from array b
ArrayList<Integer> bArrList = new ArrayList<>(IntStream.of(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

That being said and done, I'd just keep it simple and use a loop to initialize to a random value and work my way around not having to use arrays if I'm going to require ArrayLists or vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MockNeat](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat) (disclaimer I am the author):

```
MockNeat mockNeat = MockNeat.threadLocal();
MockUnitInt intUnit = mockNeat.ints().range(0, 100);

int[] arr1 = intUnit.arrayPrimitive(100).val();
Integer[] arr2 = intUnit.array(100).val();
List<Integer> list1 = intUnit.list(100).val();
List<List<Integer>> list2 = intUnit.list(100).list(100).val();
```

The library makes it easy to describe a behaviour for generating arbitrary data, and then reuse this "behavior" and generate all kinds of structures with it.